# Initialize TinyMCE on multiple textareas - variable scope issue?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm applying tinyMCE to some textareas in WordPress metaboxes. I'm going to be adding areas dynamically so I can't use the `wp_editor()` function. I'm pretty close but I am stumped on passing some settings.

As is, the following code only seems to initialize the last textarea in the set. However, if you uncomment the `var settings` declaration inside the `.each()` loop, then they are all activated. I presume this has something to do with scope, because I'm totally lost as I can't reproduce it on my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helgatheviking/gDNdz/5/).

Eventually, I would like to *borrow* the default post editor's settings and then just change the selector... possibly via jQuery's `.extend()`. I suppose I could run the `.extend()` every time withing the `.each()`, but that seems inefficient.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var settings = { menubar : false };

    $('textarea.wp-editor-area').each( function( i ) {  
            var id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
            if ( !id) {
                id = 'mceEditor-' + ( i );
                $( this ).attr( 'id', id );
            }  

            //var settings = { menubar : false };
            settings.selector = "#" + id ;

            try {
                tinymce.init( settings );

            } catch(e) {}

        });  //end each 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/helgatheviking/gDNdz/5/

On another note, the `.each()` loop works if I use `tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', true, id );` Is there any noticeable difference between the `.execCommand()` and `.init()`?  It also works if I use a different tinyMCE  mode (such as specific_textareas), I am just now really curious why it would work in my fiddle but not in my site.

Comment: When I'm cloning WP editors I use a combination of the init method to populate TMCE settings, and the tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', true, id ) method to actually add the editor to the page. My understanding is that the init method provides parameters, and the mceAddEditor command instantiates the editor using the settings you've provided in the init object. I don't provide a selector parameter, its provided via the ID param of the 'mceAddEditor' command.

Comment: I've had some level of success with `mceAddEditor` too. I was just stumped on why the looped `init` method was working in a fiddle but not in the WP admin.

Comment: You should be able to get the default pages editor settings by hooking into `do_action( 'wp_tiny_mce_init', self::$mce_settings )`

Answer (score 0):

Still can't comment...

Rather than adding them using their ID, why can't you use:

```
settings.selector: "textarea.wp-editor-area"
```

This would init all matching textareas? That way there's no need for a loop.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that worked perfectly on the the initial DOM, but didn't seem to initialize tinyMCE when I was dynamically adding text areas.

Comment: I've dynamically added textareas with jQuery but always called the full .init function with selectors and this works for me.